# How do I input the parameter with bytes4 type in Remix?

Tags: solidity, remix

I created a simple contract as blow shows. When I deployed it and try to call `get` function, I found that I couldn't input the correct parameter with `bytes4` type. No matter I used `0x01,11,"11"...`, it always told that error encoding argument like this.

> transact to Test.get errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value" value="11" code=INVALID_ARGUMENT version=bytes/5.5.0)

> transact to Test.get errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value" value="0x6162" code=INVALID_ARGUMENT version=bytes/5.5.0)

What should I do ?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Test {
    mapping (bytes8 => string) public  map;
    function setMapping() public {
        map["k1"] = "yes";
    }
    function get(bytes4 a) public {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enter the bytes in the hex form, undivided. Since `bytes4` is a fixed-length array of four bytes, you always need to input exactly 4 bytes (8 hex characters).

```
0x12345678
```

- `12` is the first byte
- `34` is the second byte
- etc...

---

Note: If you want to input empty bytes, you can use `00` in the location of the empty byte. Example: `0x00340078` (1st and 3rd byte are empty).